# Batch script map samba share with username and password and auto dismount

Tags: windows, batch-file, ubuntu, samba, smb

I'm trying to add a Samba share on Ubuntu to a mapped drive on Windows, from a batch script. I need to specify the username and password in the batch file to access the share. I know this is bad security, but I need it like this because the batch script will be automatically generated from something else. The share should also be unmounted after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `net use /help`, which explains how to map a share, and how to delete it.

For the "30 minutes" part, i'd use `schtasks` to create a scheduled task to run at the specified time.
If you want to stay self-contained, more modern versions of windows (7ff, i believe) support `TIMEOUT /T 1800 /NOBREAK`, which waits 1800 seconds and ignores keypresses.

Comment: ah, ok it looks like I can do it with `net use z: \\ubuntuserver\theshare /user:domain\username password` 
However, I'd really like to not go the `schtasks` route, self contained in the batch script would be better, any way to pause or set a timer? After which this should work `net use z: /delete` I'll report back after testing.